# How To convert certain object properties to json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php class, let say:

```
class StudentDisplay{
private $student_id;
private $student_display;

function getStudent_id() {
    return $this->student_id;
}

function getStudent_display() {
    return $this->student_display;
}

function setStudent_id($student_id) {
    $this->student_id = $student_id;
}

function setStudent_display($student_display) {
    $this->student_display = $student_display;
}
```

}
 But when I do json encode on this object, I want only the student_id property displayed.

Is there a way i can easily go about this?

Comment: `$result = json_encode($object->getStudent_id());` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver, that won't work, since it's certain properties. It's not just one property i need printed. when I call json encode on the object, certain properties. If there is a way I can mark those properties as non json serializable for instance..

Comment: That's not what you said: _I want only the student_id property displayed_.

Answer (score 1):

Your object needs to implement `JsonSerializable` interface.

```
class StudentDisplay implements JsonSerializable {
```

Then add whatever you want returned in `jsonSerialize` method.

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'student_id' => $this->student_id,
    ];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php